# Custom WebHook For Rejecting Push for Github Branch Name and Commit Message

Tags: git, github, webhooks, git-branch, github-webhook

I am trying to setup a pre-receive hook in Github that we will be using to avoid unnecessary commits. I am looking for few rules to be maintained

Requiring a custom commit message.
Every commit should include an existing JIRA at the beginning example `JIRA-XXX | Commit message`

Enforce this on any pull request as well.

Requiring a branch name format.

example: `abc_devName_some_br_name_jira_XXX`

Can anybody here help me, how can this be done ?

Comment: #1 Do you want to decline a pull request if commits message does not meet your pattern? #2 Do you have some continuous integration server?

Comment: @JRichardsz answer to #1 Yes, Push will be declines. #2 Yes we have CI server

Comment: #1 Is your c.i server able to receive the pull request event? or just the push event? #2 is your c.i server able to clone the repository and performs advanced git commands on the repository? #3 Pull request could be declined. Git push cannot be declined. #4 Do you want to delete the commit with incorrect message or decline the pull request?

Comment: @JRichardz Answers
#1. I am not 100% sure but I think both are possible
#2 Yes
#3. PR declined should and should not be able to merge to master.
#4. Decline the pull request

Comment: @KunalVohra Is your project node-based? because in that case, you can use Husky https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=usage

Comment: Its Go lang @AshishRawat

Comment: The cornerstone of any automation is that your ci server can receive the webhook notification which is a json containing the event information. Check [this](https://jrichardsz.github.io/devops/devops-with-git-and-jenkins-using-webhooks) for jenkins. If your c-i server is "acme", I think your question should change slightly: How decline github pull request based on commit message using acme? If you agree with this, add the name of your ci server and the installed webhook plugins to the question details.

Comment: @Jrichardsz I think both ways is needed. Code push should be stopped first of all. And by any case if it reaches the github. PR shouldn't be successful

Comment: When `git push` is performed, the target branch receive the commit, no matter what. The only way to block the commit reception is using branch permissions [github, bitbucket, gitlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7mag.png). These rules are created at the repository creation moment and usually the input parameters are just the branch name and role group. Commit message is not available in these rules. That said, there are not options in common platforms to deny or prohibit the commit reception based on commit message pattern.

Comment: The only way using ci server is receive the commit, notify to the ci server using webhooks, evaluate the commit message applying some logic and then deny the pull request, revert commit on the branch using git commands, notify  by email, etc.  I think deny the pull request is enough. Revert the commit in the developer branch, could delete the developer work. Common practice is **protect** the master branch from accidental commits. In this case, the branch permissions feature in common platforms is enough.

Answer (score 7):

Git webhooks and git hooks are different options. We can catalog in:

- Client-Side Git Hooks

  - works at developer machine level
- Server-Side Git Hooks

  - works at git server machine level
- WebHooks

  - works notifying the event to a external services (jenkins, travis, circleci, etc) after the event in case of **git push**

Your title question say "webhooks" but your question details say "pre-receive hook", so that is the first thing to clarify: As I know, there are different  options that works separately.

I will show you some options to accomplish your goal:

## Branch Protection

Used to protect master branch of accidental pushes.

These rules are created at the repository creation moment and usually the input parameters are just the branch name and role group. Commit message is not available in these rules.

Github sample

[image: github]

More details here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule#about-branch-protection-rules

Bitbucket sample

[image: bitbucket]

## webhooks

Easy way, but happen after **git push** event. Steps:

- configure the webhook pointing to your c.i server, in the settings section of your git platform (github in your case)
- in your c.i server create a job/task to receive the event details (a big json containing a lot of information like: repository name, branch name, author mail,  commit id, commit message)
- in this job/task put your logic to evaluate if commit message follow your guidelines.
- if commit message doesn't meet your guidelines, you can:

  - notify by mail
  - using some privileged account, revert the commit. This is some dangerous action for my opinion because the developer work could be deleted.
  - search a pull request related to commit and deny it or create another webhook just for pull request event and do the same.

## Github server hook

[pre-receive](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/rest/reference/enterprise-admin#repository-pre-receive-hooks) hook feature is available only for **GitHub Enterprise**

Basically this is a shell script which will run in the server of your github enterprise.

I think is similar to the git server side hooks. I found this link with steps to register, update and delete hooks:

- [Managing pre-receive hooks on the GitHub Enterprise Server appliance](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/admin/policies/enforcing-policy-with-pre-receive-hooks/managing-pre-receive-hooks-on-the-github-enterprise-server-appliance)

Now, how to create the script:

- [Creating a pre-receive hook script](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/admin/policies/enforcing-policy-with-pre-receive-hooks/creating-a-pre-receive-hook-script)

The problem as I found is that **git message** string is not a ready to use variable. **In webhooks it is!!**

If you want to access to the commit message, you will need to test this

- [git pre receive hook to check commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39420605/3957754)

The main idea is having the commit id, you can access to some file in git server, which contains the message:

```
tree cfda3bf37b78aef7f4daf
parent 085bb3306e7e7
author Scott Chacon <schacon@gmail.com> 1205815931 -0700
committer Scott Chacon <schacon@gmail.com> 1240030591 -0700

I'm the message sent by the developer
```

If you achieve that, you could add a message to be showed when your developer performs a **git push** with an invalid git message:

```
> Counting objects: 7, done.
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
> Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
> Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 700 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
> Total 7 (delta 0), reused 7 (delta 0)
> remote: error: rejecting all pushes
> To git@192.168.99.100:test.git
>  ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: commit message does not meet the rule xyz
```

## Server-Side Git Hooks

Similar to github enterprise feature. I think that install a git server in cloud or on-premise machine is not a common practice due to the ready to use services (github, bitbucket, gitlab, etc) but it is an option.

You can find more details [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

As in github enterprise server, you will not have the commit message ready to use as variable. Check this:

- [git pre receive hook to check commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39420605/3957754)

## Client-Side Git Hooks

The same idea but at developer machine level. More details [here](https://githooks.com/)

Basically in the .git folder of any repository in the machine of your developers, you can put these scripts.

Due that this script is shell script, you will have the same problem: git message is not a ready to use variable

## References

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks
- https://githooks.com/
- [git pre receive hook to check commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419360/git-pre-receive-hook-to-check-commit-message)
- https://support.gitkraken.com/working-with-repositories/githooksexample/
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#Server-Side-Hook
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks
- https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/admin/policies/enforcing-policy-with-pre-receive-hooks/managing-pre-receive-hooks-on-the-github-enterprise-server-appliance
- https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/admin/policies/enforcing-policy-with-pre-receive-hooks/creating-a-pre-receive-hook-script
- https://github.community/t/using-pre-receive-hooks-in-github-enterprise/13506
- https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule
- [Link to the issue number on GitHub within a commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262/link-to-the-issue-number-on-github-within-a-commit-message/6742691#6742691)
- [Is it possible to reject a commit on Github if the commit isn't formatted correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764942/is-it-possible-to-reject-a-commit-on-github-if-the-commit-isnt-formatted-correc)
- [Git hook to reject commits where files contain a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835998/git-hook-to-reject-commits-where-files-contain-a-specific-string)
- https://medium.com/@f3igao/get-started-with-git-hooks-5a489725c639
- [Example of a pre-receive Git hook](https://gist.github.com/Pierstoval/27e8f309034fa0ababa1)
- https://github.blog/2013-01-22-closing-issues-via-commit-messages/